# Python for loops and comprehension for loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

Can someone explain to me why would this two statements (the for loop and the comprehension ) return two different answers. I thought they were the same, just different ways of writing the statement.

Data used:

```
Top152['% Renewable'] 
Country
China                 19.754910
United States         11.570980
Japan                 10.232820
United Kingdom        10.600470
Russian Federation    17.288680
Canada                61.945430
Germany               17.901530
India                 14.969080
France                17.020280
South Korea            2.279353
Italy                 33.667230
Spain                 37.968590
Iran                   5.707721
Australia             11.810810
Brazil                69.648030
```

For loop:

```
def answer_ten():
    Top15 = answer_one()
    Top152 = Top15.copy()

    for x in Top152['% Renewable']:
        if x >= Top152['% Renewable'].median():
            Top152['HighRenew'] = 1
        else:
            Top152['HighRenew'] = 0
return Top152['HighRenew']
    answer_ten()
```

Output:

```
    Country
    China                 1
    United States         1
    Japan                 1
    United Kingdom        1
    Russian Federation    1
    Canada                1
    Germany               1
    India                 1
    France                1
    South Korea           1
    Italy                 1
    Spain                 1
    Iran                  1
    Australia             1
    Brazil                1
```

Comprehension:

```
def answer_ten():
Top15 = answer_one()
Top152 = Top15.copy()

    Top152['HighRenew'] = [1 if x >= Top152['% Renewable'].median() else 0 for x in Top152['% Renewable']]


return Top152['HighRenew']
answer_ten()
```

Output:

```
Country
China                 1
United States         0
Japan                 0
United Kingdom        0
Russian Federation    1
Canada                1
Germany               1
India                 0
France                1
South Korea           0
Italy                 1
Spain                 1
Iran                  0
Australia             0
Brazil                1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better is convert `boolean mask` to `int`, because `pandas` the fastest working with very fast vectorized functions:

```
print (Top152['% Renewable']> Top152['% Renewable'].median())
China                  True
United States         False
Japan                 False
United Kingdom        False
Russian Federation     True
Canada                 True
Germany                True
India                 False
France                False
South Korea           False
Italy                  True
Spain                  True
Iran                  False
Australia             False
Brazil                 True
Name: % Renewable, dtype: bool
```

---

```
def answer_ten():
    return (Top152['% Renewable'] > Top152['% Renewable'].median())
            .astype(int).rename('HighRenew')


print (answer_ten())
China                 1
United States         0
Japan                 0
United Kingdom        0
Russian Federation    1
Canada                1
Germany               1
India                 0
France                0
South Korea           0
Italy                 1
Spain                 1
Iran                  0
Australia             0
Brazil                1
Name: HighRenew, dtype: int32
```

For loop, very slow solution is possible use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), but faster is first solution:

```
def answer_ten():
    for idx, x in Top152.iterrows():
        if Top152.loc[idx, '% Renewable'] >= Top152['% Renewable'].median():
            Top152.loc[idx, 'HighRenew'] = 1
        else:
            Top152.loc[idx, 'HighRenew'] = 0
    return Top152['HighRenew'].astype(int)

print (answer_ten())
China                 1
United States         0
Japan                 0
United Kingdom        0
Russian Federation    1
Canada                1
Germany               1
India                 0
France                1
South Korea           0
Italy                 1
Spain                 1
Iran                  0
Australia             0
Brazil                1
Name: HighRenew, dtype: int32
```

**Timings**:

```
#[15000 rows x 1 columns]
Top152 = pd.concat([Top152]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)  

def answer_ten1():
    return (Top152['% Renewable']> Top152['% Renewable'].median()).astype(int).rename('HighRenew')

def answer_ten2():
    for idx, x in Top152.iterrows():
        if Top152.loc[idx, '% Renewable'] >= Top152['% Renewable'].median():
            Top152.loc[idx, 'HighRenew'] = 1
        else:
            Top152.loc[idx, 'HighRenew'] = 0
    return Top152['HighRenew'].astype(int)


def answer_ten3():
    Top152['HighRenew'] = [1 if x >= Top152['% Renewable'].median() else 0 for x in Top152['% Renewable']]
    return Top152['HighRenew']

print (answer_ten1())   
print (answer_ten2())
print (answer_ten3())
```

---

```
In [169]: %timeit (answer_ten1())
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop

In [170]: %timeit answer_ten2()
1 loop, best of 3: 16 s per loop

In [171]: %timeit (answer_ten3())
1 loop, best of 3: 2.67 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the **whole** column (vector) in each iteration step:

```
Top152['HighRenew'] = 1
```

Try this vectorized approach instead:

```
Top152['HighRenew'] = (Top152['% Renewable'] >= Top152['% Renewable'].median()).astype(int)
```

so your function may be implemented as follows:

```
def answer_ten():
    return (Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median()).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second approach you are editing your vector. While the for loop will save it (in the background) to avoid the unwanted edits!